# assigning data: array vs brackets, which is better?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

i'm just wondering the difference between this two, performance wise and which one is best to use

```
$data = array(
    'key1' => 'some value',
    'key2' => $some_variable
);
```

and this one

```
$data = array();  // can be omitted
$data['key1'] = 'some value';
$data['key2'] = $some_value
```

Comment: This is a ridiculously irrelevant amount of performance difference, if any even exists. Don't worry about such things until they've been proven to be a problem for you. Use whichever syntax makes the most sense for the situation.

Comment: that's depent up-on your requirement....

Comment: Performance seems an exceptionally easy thing to test here. Write a loop to make 10,000,000 of each and see how long each takes.

Comment: I've put them inside a loop (1,000,000 ) and second one was faster (half a second)!

Answer (score 2):

This comparison is not the way to think about. When you would be writing some practical code you will switch between both the methods alternatively depending upon needs of your problem. Like if you are accessing some row from a database you will have to use second one in a loop and although `array()` is rarely used but there are case when you will prefer it as string indexed array has to be assigned this way in a case where you are not getting values from `$_POST` or database. But there does exist cases when both methods can be used but you may prefer second one in a loop because your code will be shorter and you fingers have to bear less pain in assigning values to may be 10,000 entries. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Back to this question, first way will be faster, see the opcodes below:

### 1:

#### code:

```
$data = array(
    'key1' => 'some value',
    'key2' => $some_variable
);
```

#### opcode:

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   INIT_ARRAY                                       ~0      'some+value', 'key1'
   5     1      ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT                                ~0      !1, 'key2'
         2      ASSIGN                                                   !0, ~0
   6     3    > RETURN                                                   1
```

### 2:

#### code:

```
$data = array();  // can be omitted
$data['key1'] = 'some value';
$data['key2'] = $some_value
```

#### opcode:

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   INIT_ARRAY                                       ~0      
         1      ASSIGN                                                   !0, ~0
   3     2      ASSIGN_DIM                                               !0, 'key1'
         3      OP_DATA                                                  'some+value', $3
   4     4      ASSIGN_DIM                                               !0, 'key2'
         5      OP_DATA                                                  !1, $5
   5     6    > RETURN                                                   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following code:

```
<?php

$start=time();
for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++)
{
    $data = array(
        'key1' => 'some value',
        'key2' => 3
    );
}
$end=time();
$total=$end-$start;
echo "The operation took $total seconds to complete for brackets.";

$start=time();
for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++)
{
    $data = array();  // can be omitted
    $data['key1'] = 'some value';
    $data['key2'] = 3;
}
$end=time();
$total=$end-$start;
echo "The operation took $total seconds to complete for keys.";

?>
```

The output showed 3 seconds per method.

Answer: No noticable performance difference :)

Edit:

I also just copied the code and ran it on a terrible old and slow PC through a CLI (also upped the loop in each to be 100,000,000 iterations) with the following results:

First method 52 seconds, second method 59 seconds. So, ever so slight difference, but across a hundred million iterations, it's pretty much use whatever you want :)